# Showing $x^TAx\geq c|x|^2$ using continuity of $x^TAx$.

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, multivariable-calculus, continuity

[Text In Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWloR.png)

With regards to the link above, how would I show the existence of such a constant $c$ using the continuity of $x^TAx$?  I've seen people show this using linear algebra, but my instructor specifically asked us not to do that.  In the problem I'm adapting this to, $A$ is a Hessian matrix of a $C^3$ function, and his hint was to think of $x^TAx$ as a function and to see what we could say of it's continuity.

Comment: Consider the values of that function on the compact (in finite dimension) set $\{x:\ \|x\|=1\}$. Take $c$ the minimum of those. Then for arbitrary non-zero $y=\|y\|\frac{y}{\|y\|}$ you have that $y^TAy=\|y\|^2(y/\|y\|)^TA(y/\|y\|)\geq \|y\|^2c$.

Comment: Makes sense @conditionalMethod.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A quadratic form $Q(X)=X^T A X$ is an homogeneous function, i.e. $Q(\lambda X) = \lambda^2 Q(X)$. In particular, $Q(X) = Q\left(\|X\| \frac{x}{\|X\|}\right) = \|X\|^2 Q\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|}\right)$. Since $Q$ is continuous over the compact set $K=\{Y \in \mathbb{R}^n: \|Y\|=1\}$, it will attain a global minimum $c$ over that set, and so, we have indeed that $Q(X) \ge c \|X\|^2$. The same argument guarantees that you have a constant $C$ such that $Q(X) \leq C \|X\|^2$.